# NLog Web - AspNet-User-Identity without domain

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I'm currently using the NLog.Web package for writing my .Net logs in my application.
After reading the NLog.Web I've noticed that unlike the `${windows-identity}` layout renderer, the `${aspnet-user-identity}` layout renderer got no domain parameter for it.

For example, if I want to log the current running windows identity, it logs out: `domain\user`, but when specifying `domain=false`, it logs only user.

How do I implement this kind of ability with the `${aspnet-user-identity}`? Because when I configured `${aspnet-user-identity:domain=false}` it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different way to solve this issue @Julian

in the NLog.config file, i created a variable:

```
<variable name="aspnetIdentity" value="${replace:searchFor=^\\w+\\\\:replaceWith=:regex=true:inner=${aspnet-user-identity}}" />
```

As defined in the variable, the regex searches for at least one word (at the start) and finally searching for a backslash.
the other backslashes are written to escape special characters and also double backslashing. Finally, what was found (it's the domain name) will be replaced with an empty string and therefore I got only the username and not the Domain\Username

Thanks for the help @Julian

Answer (score 1):

The `WindowsIdentity.Name`, used in NLog, will always give the full name, including domain.

> The logon name is in the form DOMAIN\USERNAME.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.name(v=vs.110).aspx

I think you need a custom layout renderer, and split it by-hand on the `/`.

Something like this: (maybe also add soms checks for outOfIndex)

```
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;

....

//register ${my-aspnet-user-identity}
LayoutRenderer.Register("my-aspnet-user-identity",
              (logEvent) => HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name?.Split('/')[1]);
```

Register it as soon as possible.